# How to check is page is redirected from previous page or not in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Page  1 on button click I redirect the page to page 2 with msgid, and in page 2 in page load I check whether the previous page is valid. So i check `(this.Page.PreviousPage != null)` but this is always null and the page gets redirected to page 1. I am doing this so that no one can change the msgid in the url. How can I solve this issues. thanks

Page1:

```
  int msgid = Convert.ToInt32(Hidden_MsgID.Value);
    string url = "Page2.aspx?MsgID=" + msgid;
    Response.Redirect(url);
```

Page2:

```
if (this.Page.PreviousPage != null)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
                }
```

instead of response.redirect I used server . transfer and it works
    Server.Transfer(string.Format("ResponseMetric.aspx?MsgID={0}", msgid));

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`PreviousPage` does only work with `Server.Transfer` and/or cross-page-posting: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

elements for your solution available [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=89): work with `this.Request.UrlReferrer`

Comment: @Murthy were does the Exception occur - which line/action causes it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a session variable to check if the flow is followed as well..
Before your redirect you can set

```
Session["PREVPAGE"] = "fooo.aspx";
```

And retrieve it in the page load of the second page..

Comment: `Session` is not 100% reliable - what if you do a recycle meanwhile?